# usar ajax ou deixar formulário oculto?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Bom dia!

Estou preparando um formulário, e esse formulário contém um campo de select.
Dependendo do campo select que a pessoa escolher, deve ser mostrado novos campos, exclusivos para cada opção.

A pergunta é:
Devo deixar esses campos previamente carregados e deixa-los ocultos(e obviamente mostrar conforme a opção foi selecionada), ou devo fazer uma nova requisição com ajax e incorpora-los a página atual?

Ou quem sabe tenham uma alternativa melhor :)

Ressalto que não será feita nenhuma consulta a banco de dados ao escolher uma opção.
Deixo uma imagem abaixo para exemplificar melhor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado!

Comment: Felipe, poste o seu código por favor? Pode ser exemplo de um que estará visível e outro que deverá ficar visível após selecionar determinada opção

Comment: isso depende do seu código, como é carregado, se demoram as chamadas ajax...

Comment: Acho bem melhor deixar oculto do que fazer requisições extras ao servidor. Mas acho que a pergunta está mais baseada em opinião.